# How to assign a value to a variable returned by the http get method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to assign a value to a variable returned by the http get method?
I declared a variable `this.artists = null` in the constructor. I want to assign the value returned by $ http.get to `this.artists variable`.
`Res.data` return me object - it's ok, but I can't assign it to variable `this.artists`

```
export default class ArtistsService {
  constructor($http) {
    'ngInject';
    this.$http = $http;
    this.artists = null;
  }

 getArtists() {


return this.$http.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search? 
   q=Muse&type=track%2Cartist&market=US&limit=10&offset=5", 
    {headers: {
        'Authorization': <Authorization>}, params 
   }).then(function mySuccess(res) {
        this.artists = res.data;

        console.log(this.artists);

        }).catch( function myError(res) {

        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

In the `showClosureExample` method notice how the `bound` method is a [Fat Arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). The fat arrow makes it's Function scope `lexical`y bound to its parents context where as `scoped` is bound to itself ([Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) `Scope`).
When we reference `this` in `scoped` we get the Function's context and when we log `this` in `bound` we get the context of `Foo` (`this.foo`)

```js
class Foo {
    constructor () {
    this.foo = null
    
    this.showClosureExample()
  }
  
  showClosureExample () {
    const scoped = function () {
      console.log(this)
    }
    
    const bound = () => {
      console.log(this)
    }
    
    scoped()  // Logs undefined
    bound()   // Logs the properties of Foo
  }
}

new Foo()
```

Try having your `then` callbacks be lexical(y) bound.

If you wish to not use Fat Arrows you could use the `Bind` Method to pass the context to your callback functions

```js
class Foo {
    constructor () {
    this.foo = null
    
    this.showClosureExample()
  }
  
  showClosureExample () {
    const boundToFoo = function () {
      console.log(this)
    }.bind(this)
    
    boundToFoo()  // Logs the properties of Foo
  }
}

new Foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

In you Then closure, this.artists does not exist. 
You have two options

1. async/await - you probably want this task to be done in the background so async/await isn't ideal!
2. Call a set method in your Then block

e.g.

```
getArtists() {


this.$http.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search? 
     q=Muse&type=track%2Cartist&market=US&limit=10&offset=5", 
    {headers: {
    'Authorization': <Authorization>}, params 
    }).then(function mySuccess(res) {
    //this.artists = res.data;

    setArtists(res.data);

    }).catch( function myError(res) {

    });
};
}

setArtists(artists) {
   this.artists = artists
}
```